# Get Minimum and Maximum Date from a multidimensional object and create new object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a object like below

```
SpecialObj=
{   
    "dataarray-345":
    [
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 5000, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},
        {lqd: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"},
        {lqd: 4500, date: "2017-08-18 11:00:00"},
        {lqd: 1500, date: "2017-08-18 11:30:00"}
    ],
    "dataarray-123":
    [
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 5000, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},
        {lqd: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"},
        {lqd: 4500, date: "2017-08-18 11:00:00"}
    ],
    "dataarray-127":
    [
        {lqd: 5000, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},
        {lqd: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"},
        {lqd: 4500, date: "2017-08-18 11:00:00"},
        {lqd: 1500, date: "2017-08-18 11:30:00"},
        {lqd: 2500, date: "2017-08-18 12:00:00"},
        {lqd: 3500, date: "2017-08-18 12:30:00"},
        {lqd: 8500, date: "2017-08-18 13:00:00"},
        {lqd: 9500, date: "2017-08-18 13:30:00"},
        {lqd: 6500, date: "2017-08-18 14:00:00"}
    ]
}
```

After matching with each dataarray-345, dataarray-123, dataarray-127 Need to fiend the min and max date and create a new object like below...

```
SpecialObj:
{   
    dataarray-345:
    [
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 6500, date: "2017-08-18 14:00:00"}
    ],
    dataarray-123:
    [
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 6500, date: "2017-08-18 14:00:00"}
    ],
    dataarray-127:
    [
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 6500, date: "2017-08-18 14:00:00"}
    ]
}
```

That means all the object should be updated with min and max data set.

Can you please help me to create this object with simple javascript.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: why would you want all object have the same data

Comment: This is not valid JSON syntax. Are those actually *arrays* of objects?

Comment: Yes, we can help you fix the problem with your code. You need to post it for that, however. Have you even attempted to solve this yourself?

Comment: @juvian, due to some project requirement I need that.

Comment: @Bergi SpecialObj is an object. I have tried with some different approach but could not get the solution.

Comment: @Ajay Yes, `SpecialObj` is an object, but its property value should not.

Comment: Yes @Bergi you are right, all other are array.

Comment: @Ajay Then please [edit] your question to fix that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156384/discussion-between-ajay-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do something like this: iterate all your object properties, iterate their arrays and always keep current mininum and maximum found. Then just create another object with the new format.

Be careful that in this solution I use the same min and max objects to fill the new object arrays so if you plan on changing a value in one of them, change will reflect on the others as well as it is the same reference.

```js
var SpecialObj = 
{   
    "obj-1": [
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 5000, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},
        {lqd: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"},
        {lqd: 4500, date: "2017-08-18 11:00:00"},
        {lqd: 1500, date: "2017-08-18 11:30:00"}
    ],
    "obj-2":
    [
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 5000, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},
        {lqd: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"},
    ],
    "obj-3":
    [
        {lqd: 5000, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},
        {lqd: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"},
        {lqd: 4500, date: "2017-08-18 11:00:00"},
        {lqd: 1500, date: "2017-08-18 11:30:00"},
        {lqd: 2500, date: "2017-08-18 12:00:00"},
        {lqd: 3500, date: "2017-08-18 12:30:00"},
        {lqd: 8500, date: "2017-08-18 13:00:00"},
        {lqd: 9500, date: "2017-08-18 13:30:00"},
        {lqd: 6500, date: "2017-08-18 14:00:00"}
    ]
}

var min = null, max = null;

for (var key in SpecialObj) {
  var arr = SpecialObj[key];
  arr.forEach(function(obj){
      if (min == null || new Date(obj.date) < new Date(min.date)) min = obj; 
      if (max == null || new Date(obj.date) > new Date(max.date)) max = obj;
  })
}

var newObj = {}

for (var key in SpecialObj) {
  newObj[key] = [min, max];
}

console.log(newObj)
```